# What defines the speed of waves?

Tags: waves, speed-of-light, acoustics, gravitational-waves

Why the speed of sound or speed of electromagnetic/gravitational waves have values which they have? What defines it? Why do it not two times slower or two times faster, for i.e.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Experimentally, you can measure it.

**Wave equation.**

Mathematically, we're talking about physical processes whose governing equations are formally the same, i.e. the **wave equation** (see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation the mathematical properties of the equation, its solutions and their properties, included the meaning of the propagation speed) that can be written as

$\dfrac{1}{c^2}\dfrac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial t^2} - \Delta \phi = 0$,

where $\phi$ represents the physical quantity whose perturbations propagates as waves, and $c$ is the speed of the perturbation.

**Wave equation in Electromagnetism.**
As an example (see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_wave_equation), you can get a homogeneous wave equation for the electric field or for the magnetic field (or equivalently for the potentials), combining Maxwell's equations in vacuum, in absence of electric charges or currents,

$\varepsilon_0 \mu_0 \dfrac{\partial^2 \mathbf{E}}{\partial t^2} - \Delta \mathbf{E} = \mathbf{0}$,

and thus you can recognize a wave equation with speed of the perturbations in the electromagnetic field, i.e. the **speed of light in vacuum**, is equal to $c^2 = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\varepsilon_0 \mu_0}}$.

**Wave equation for sound.**
You can get a wave equation governing the evolution of small perturbations of pressure field and other thermodynamic variables (here indicated with $(\cdot)'$) propagating in a compressible fluid at rest, through linearization of the equations of fluid dynamics around the steady fields (indicated here with the subscripts $0$)

$\dfrac{1}{\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial \rho}\right)_s(\rho_0,s_0)} \dfrac{\partial^2 p'}{\partial t^2} - \Delta p' = 0$,

being $p'(x,t)$ the pressure field small perturbation of the steady condition $P_0$, and $c^2(\rho_0,s_0) = \left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial \rho}\right)_s (\rho_0,s_0)$ the **speed of sound** in the medium (measured in the reference condition of the fluid at rest), i.e. the velocity of propagation of the perturbations in $p'(x,t)$.